# Compiling with header files

Tags: c, compilation, header-files

Compiling the file main.c with:

```
gcc main1.c -o final
```

gives me:

```
/tmp/cc1cwhAP.o: In function `main':
main1.c:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `hi'
main1.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `hi'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**main1.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "incl.h"

int main(void)
{
 hi = 1;
 printf("hi = %d",hi);
 return(0);
}
```

**incl.h:**

```
extern int hi;
```

What am I doing wrong? (Please be verbose with your answers)

Removing the `extern` keyword solves the issue, but I want to be able to use the `hi` variable in other source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget about header files for a bit (after all their contents are inserted inside source files during compilation and they only exist during pre-processing). They're only an easy way to use the same code in several source files (think copy/paste). So, in the interest of efficiency, that duplicated code should **do** nothing; or we risk doing something more than once.

```
int x; /* puts aside a memory area with space for an int and call it x */
extern int x; /* tell the compiler that x exists and it is an int */
```

Which of the above does less? That's the one to put in a header file. But as we've told the compiler `x` exists, we need to actually define it somewhere. The best place to define it is in a source file.

*As header files don't do anything, they're pretty much safe to insert into lots of source files*.

Now, back to header files. They're usually linked to a specific source file (through their names: foobar.h is linked to foobar.c). This is a good method to identify where **declarations** in the header file are **defined**.

```
/* foobar.h */
extern int x;
void myfoo(int);
```

After seeing this header file, I'd expect `foobar.c` to contain the definition of `x` and `myfoo`.

```
/* foobar.c */
int x;                /* global x. BAD BAD BAD */
void myfoo(int alpha) { x = !x; return x ? alpha : 0; }
```

---

**Why globals are bad?**

quote from http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

> Really Bad Reasons to Use Global Variables
>
> - "I'm a slow typist. Globals save me keystrokes."
> - "I don't want to pass it around all the time."

Comment: +1: Great answer. By the way, if I want to include  `foobar.h` in another source file, shouldn't the function prototype in it also bear the `extern` keyword?

Comment: You're thinking right :) ... but `extern` is already assumed for functions: it's redundant to add it (no harm in doing so)

Answer (score 3):

You've told the compiler that there exist a variable called `hi`, but you have not actually defined it.

There's two ways to solve this:

1. Drop the `extern` keyword in the declaration in the header file. This is **BAD**!
2. Declare the variable in a source file. This can be either the main1.c or another source file, that you link into the program. This is the good way.

Comment: 3. Do not use global variables at all. This is the better way :)

Comment: Why is it bad to use the `extern` keyword in a header file?

Comment: pmg: Agreed, but that is beside the problem that the original poster was asking about :)

Comment: Kedar: It's not bad in itself to use the extern keyword. It is bad to declare variables in header files (without the extern keyword.)

Comment: @harald, your comment seems to be in contradiction to your point no. 1

Comment: Kedar: Nope, I say it is bad to remove the extern keyword in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable extern, it means to the compiler that it will be defined in some c modules and should be found during linking.

You still need to define a global `int hi` in one .c file.
Any .c file including your header file will be able to use it.

Comment: It's unusual to write `C` in cpp files :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the actual `int hi` in one of your source codes. And then extern will reference to that.